# Compact and connected LOTS

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

Let $X$ be a compact and connected LOTS (linearly-ordered topological space).
The topology on $X$ is the order topology.

Let $a<b\in X$.

I am trying to prove the following:

> For every interval $(a,b)\subseteq X$ there exists a non-trivial order-preserving homeomorphism $f$ such that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in X\smallsetminus (a,b)$.

I'm having trouble proving it. So I started thinking, maybe there is a counter example to this claim?

Any hints, ideas or references would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is at least consistent that there be a counterexample. Specifically, assume the [combinatorial principle $\Diamond$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_principle), which is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$; then there is a rigid [Suslin continuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem) $X$. $X$ is densely ordered and Dedekind complete, so it’s connected, and rigidity here means that it admits no non-trivial order-automorphism. A relatively accessible reference is Section $6$ of S. Todočević, ‘Trees and Linearly Ordered Sets’, in the *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*, K. Kunen & J.E. Vaughan, eds., North Holland, $1984$.

Comment: Brian, could you take a look at the tag wiki/excerpt for [tag:order-topology]? I've tried to make it look reasonable, but you could probably make it look better.

Comment: @Asaf: I’d use slightly different notation, but what you have looks pretty good. I do have one thought, though? Do you think that it would be good to include GO-spaces (generalized ordered spaces) here as well? (You probably know, but if not: they’re spaces with a linear order and a base of intervals, not necessarily open. Equivalently, they’re subspaces of LOTSs.)

Comment: I've never heard about GO spaces. Chess spaces, sure. Checkers spaces, sure. Even Backgammon spaces. But GO spaces? No. In any case, maybe it deserves a mention, and a link to a further reference.

Comment: Thank you very much @BrianM.Scott! I looked up "Trees and linearly ordered sets". Suslin continuum is a great example of a rigid continuum, and it is linearly ordered and connected (like I wanted). But unless I am missing something, it is not compact, is it? Do you know if it admits a compactification (that preserves the rigidity)?

Comment: @Ludolila: You’re very welcome. It’s Dedekind complete, which means that either it’s compact, or it fails to be compact only because it’s missing one or both endpoints. In that case adding the endpoint(s) makes it compact without affecting the other properties.